# How do I make strftime and GROUP and WHERE work in Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sqlite

This is from my Rails 5 app and works against Sqlite in development but I can get it to work in production against Postgres.  I have played with and googled it etc but can't quite work it out.  Thanks in advance:

Works in Sqlite>

```
Dailylog.select("date").group("strftime('%m', date)").where(user_id: user)
```

Most recent try in Postgres>

```
Dailylog.select("date").group(extract(month from "date")).where(user_id: user)
```

Comment: `strftime()` is not a Postgres function.  You can review Postgres date/time functions in the documentation:  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`date_part`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html) function in Postgres like this

```
Dailylog.select("date_part('month', date)")
 .group("date_part('month', date)")
 .where(user_id: user)
```

And some advice as a side note, please use Postgres in development too, it saves you many headaches.

Comment: Hi

That helps but now I have a different error!!

    (PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "dailylogs.date" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function